# Customized function for manipulation of data and plotting

Tags: plotting, import

I have a number of datasets (csv) which require the same manipulation and plotting, but I don't want to repeatedly write the same set of code again and again. What is the best way to do this?

Piece of code looks like this -

```
data1 = Import["sample_data_1.csv", "CSV"];
data1 = data1[[11 ;; -1, All]];
Bfield = data1[[All, 1]];
MOKEvoltage = data1[[All, 2]];
data1list = Transpose@{Bfield, MOKEvoltage};
p1 = ListPlot[data1list]
```

Now I wat to repeat the same procedure for "sample_data_2.csv","sample_data_3.csv", and so on.

What is the most efficient way to do so?

Comment: Do you want to keep the `Bfield` and `MOKEvoltage` for each file?

Comment: No I don't need it for every file.

Answer (score 1):

```
files = {"sample_data_1.csv", "sample_data_2.csv", "sample_data_3.csv"}

plot[file_] := Module[{data1, Bfield, MOKEvoltage, data1list},
  data1 = Import[file, "CSV"];
  data1 = data1[[11 ;; -1, All]];
  Bfield = data1[[All, 1]];
  MOKEvoltage = data1[[All, 2]];
  data1list = Transpose@{Bfield, MOKEvoltage};
  ListPlot[data1list]]

plot /@ files
```

Comment: `files = "sample_data_" <> ToString[#] <> ".csv" & /@ Range[10]` to create the filenames through sample_data_10.csv

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to plot each data set, most of the manipulation cancels itself out.

```
With[{data = {{a, b}, {c, d}}}, Transpose@{data[[;; , 1]], data[[;; , 2]]}]
```

> {{a, b}, {c, d}}

In the end what you want is

```
ListPlot[Import[#][[11 ;;]]] & /@ {"sample_data_1.csv", "sample_data_2.csv", ...}
```

For example

```
ListPlot[#[[11 ;;]]] & /@ RandomReal[{0., 1.}, {2, 20, 2}] // GraphicsRow
```

[image]